# Тормозит скрол UITableView

Tags: objective-c, ios, прокрутка, uitableview

Доброе время суток, сегодня солкнулся с проблемой, суть:
При разном количестве данных глючил скролл в таблице, ячейки кастомные, в них картинка и надпись, код следующий:

```
/* Выбираю данных из базы данных, запросом. */
- (NSArray *)arrayLoadScanningHistory {
    return [SQLQuery selectAllItems];
}

/* Заполняю ячейки */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *rindDetailCell = [[self tableViewHstory] dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"RingDetailCell"];
    if (!rindDetailCell) {
        rindDetailCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"RingDetailCell"];
    }

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [[self arrayLoadScanningHistory] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);

    [[rindDetailCell textLabel] setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"barcode_code"]];
    [[rindDetailCell detailTextLabel] setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"create_data"]];

    return rindDetailCell;
}
```

При таком коде таблица тормозит при скроле, её дергает, заметно на iOS6/7 на реальном устройстве лаги такие же как и на симуляторе, в чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема скорее всего в том, что вы очень часто дергаете базу данных.
Вытащите данные один раз и покладите их в кэш, что-то типа:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.cachedHistory = [self arrayLoadScanningHistory];
}
...
NSDictionary *dictionary = [self.cachedHistory objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
NSLog(@"%@", dictionary);

[[rindDetailCell textLabel] setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"barcode_code"]];
[[rindDetailCell detailTextLabel] setText:[dictionary objectForKey:@"create_data"]];
```

Кроме того, создайте полноценные объекты для своих моделей, вместо хранения данных в словарях.

Вероятно, это не повлияет на скорость, но код будет в разы читабельнее и чище.

Comment: Вы были правы, проблема устранена :)
Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Не за что, будьте внимательны ;)

Answer (score 1):

Зачем вы выполняете запрос к базе данных для каждой ячейки?
Вам нужно вынести этот запрос

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [[self arrayLoadScanningHistory] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

в другое место, например во viewDidLoad.